# Align Text in List in Div with CSS in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I have a `div` where I need to align text in a vertical fashion like in a list (`ul`/`li`). I've tried lists, table cells, paragraphs and a few other things with no success. Most of my attempts caused the results to be outside of my containing divs - `.header` and `.headerright`.

Here's my stripped down code:

**HTML :**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerleft">
    </div>
    <div class="headerright">
            Line 1 Text
            Line 2
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
div.header {
    height:75px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
    div.headerleft {
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 75px;
}

div.headerright {
    border: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 75px;
}
```

What I need is the text "Line 1 Text" and "Line 2" to appear like in a list with "Line 2" appearing under "Line 1 Text". This block of text should be centered in the containing div and "Line 2" should be centered under "Line 1 Text" like here:

Line 1 Text
   Line 2

The only browser I'm concerned about is IE9. How can this be done? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your text inside `span` elements. It works for me.

**CSS :**

```
div.headerright {
    border: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* css rule to display span elements.  */
span{
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerleft">
    </div>
    <div class="headerright">
        <span>Line 1 Text</span>
        <span>Line 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to be suggest this as well, but I was going for minimal markup changes. +1

Comment: if you think this help you get the desired I suggest mark as the answer.

Comment: I am not the question asker. I have also provided an answer. See the other solution. I was giving you a +1 because your solution should work as well as mine does.

Comment: sorry @tw16 for the misunderstanding thanks in advance for the +1.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. Neither the BR or SPAN tags worked. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zKHh5/

Comment: @Nudier - The SPAN tag pushed the text outside of the headerright div. Check the fiddle and see.

Comment: @Bob I have update the code, I have added a border to the headerright div and the span tag does not push the text outside the div, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VT94a/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems like you have tried to change your html a number of times. A very simple way to do it would be to add a `<br />` `and use text-align:center`.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/WPBNr/

**HTML :**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerleft">
    </div>
    <div class="headerright">
            Line 1 Text<br /> <!-- Added break tag -->
            Line 2
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.headerright{
    border: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 75px;
    text-align: center; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought but the <BR /> tag caused the text to push outside of the divs. All the code is there, try it and see.

Comment: @Bob: I cannot recreate the issue. You would need to provide a link to the site or recreate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net. However the code above should definitely should work.

Comment: @Bob: As you can see in my original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WPBNr/) in my answer and now this updated version of yours: http://jsfiddle.net/zKHh5/1/ it does not push the text out of the div. Though you may want to adjust your line-height for a smaller gap.