# Internet Explorer 9 doesn't align text in div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have a problem concerning IE9 and CSS.

I have a HTML5 form where I want to align the button on the right of te page. But only in IE9, it right aligns to a div where it seems not to have any connection to.

In Chrome and Firefox it looks like this:
[image]

That is the desired outcome.

But in IE9, it looks like this:
[image]

When I play around with the F12 Developer tools settings, it works whe I choose "Document Mode: IE7 standards" and any Browser mode.

HTML looks like this and is HTML5 validated on http://html5.validator.nu/:
[image]
As you can see this div is not related to the other divs.

The style window looks like this (all css files are css3 valid):
[image]

I have already tried to place a span like suggested here:
[Align Text in List in Div with CSS in Internet Explorer 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575065/align-text-in-list-in-div-with-css-in-internet-explorer-9)

Any other suggestions are welcome, or work-arounds that will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out. Adding the following line before each dubhead div did the trick:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

References:
- [What is the use of style="clear:both"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012131/what-is-the-use-of-style-clearboth)